# How to use cloud with ATG

Tags: cloud, atg

Is  Store.KnowledgeBase Module of CommerceReferenceStore in ATG is for Cloud Service? If Yes then how to check the service invocation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is cloud based. It is known as `RightNow` and the documentation to configure this inside the Commerce Reference Store is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/CRS.10-2/ATGCRSOverview/html/s1701oraclerightnowknowledgecloudserv01.html)